# My if statement isnt working

Tags: batch-file

```
if %STRE%+%LUCKE%GTR%STR%+%LUCK% echo boo
if %STRE%+%LUCKE%LSS%STR%+%LUCK% echo yay!
pause
```

I'm new to batch and this is probably way off but some help would be nice :)
It either just skips this or says echo is unexpected at this time or something along those lines.

Answer (score 1):

You require a separator between the strings and the comparison operator.

```
if %STRE%+%LUCKE% GTR %STR%+%LUCK% echo boo
if %STRE%+%LUCKE% LSS %STR%+%LUCK% echo yay!
```